# Can a .cs file override the code in the bin file for a compiled Asp.net site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have take over a old asp.net website and there is no Visual Studio Project for it. If i want to change some functionality, is there a way to put in a .cs file overriding the logic in the bin file?

Comment: Depends an the original code. You would need something like polymorphism: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_code

Comment: Not having a VS project is fine for a website, but do you have the CS files? If the site was built to allow single page assemblies, you could change only the pages that need to be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any other solution but one.

You can decompile the whole dll, create a new project and attach all classes there. Then recompile and replace an old dll with a new one.

You may need to decompile the whole web site, as it is likely there will be some dependencies to other dlls.

Comment: In most cases this will be the only way. But if the original used DI and IOC, you may be able to do something. For instance write a new implementation of an interface and resolve it via "Unity" or another IOC container.

Comment: i was afraid of this, its a huge old project no interfaces used..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles across this question, I'd like to suggest an alternate approach. Take a look at [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody). Fody is an IL weaving tool which allows you to weave in changes to existing .dll compiled files. Here is a [Basic Fody Addin Project](https://github.com/Fody/BasicFodyAddin). You'll notice Fody would allow you to inject or 'weave' code changes into the IL without a decompile.